# Как правильно нужно формировать json в php?

Tags: php, json

Вывожу значение из `mysqld` `json`, через `php`. Но проблема состоит в том, что `json` получается не совсем валидный.

Проблема в том что нет **запятой** между скобками.

**Получается `json` такого вида:**

```
{
  {
    "id": "1",
    "tag_name": "span",
  }
  {
    "id": "2",
    "tag_name": "div"
  }
}
```

А нужно вот так:

```
{
   {
      "id": "1",
      "tag_name": "span",
   },
   {
      "id": "2",
      "tag_name": "div"
   }
}
```

**Вот пример моего кода:**

```
$json_data = array('id' => $row['id'], 'tag_name' => $row['tag_name']);
json_encode($json_data);
```

Как сделать валидный `json` ?

Comment: Собрать массив массивов, а не выводить каждый по отдельности

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если `$row` в твоем случае это элемент перебора `foreach`

Типа:

```
foreach($rows as $row) {...}
```

То сначала надо собрать нужный тебе массив, с массивом элементов внутри (Массив массивов).

**Перед циклом объявить массив:**

```
$newArray = array();
```

**В цикле сделать примерно так:**

```
$newArray[] = array('id' => $row['id'], 'tag_name' => $row['tag_name']);
```

**После цикла получить `json`**

```
echo json_encode($newArray);
```

Answer (score 2):

Ничего специально собирать в массив не надо, все современные API имеют функции, возвращающие набор строк целиком

```
$stmt = $pdo->query("SELECT id, tag_name FROM table");
echo json_encode($stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
```

или

```
$res = $mysqli->query("SELECT id, tag_name FROM table");
echo json_encode($res->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC));
```